# Seeking world sea routes for ships

Tags: data

Where I can find world sea routes for ships?

I need it as a GeoJSON or shapefile format.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these two sources to find datasets for sea routes for ships worldwide

- [Shipping Routes (with labels) - One Year](https://sos.noaa.gov/datasets/shipping-routes-with-labels-one-year/)
- [Global Shipping Routes, Using 250 Million Data Points](https://www.visualcapitalist.com/mapped-global-shipping-routes-250-million-data-points/)